# Eclipse Disable Warnings inside Java Editor

Tags: eclipse, warnings

Usually, Eclipse shows the warning light bulbs on the left side of the Java editor.

That is fine.

Now, suddenly I see the light bulb and the warning also **INSIDE THE CODE of text editor**, what is sort of annoying. I must have changed some configuration, but  I can remember which one.

Any idea of how to remove the warning from the editor?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following Eclipse forum thread talks about this: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1102047/ .

If you follow the link to the page to https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.14/platform.php#show-markers-as-code-minings , it shows how to turn it off.